# How to send information from an app to another e-mail without using e-mail?

Tags: android-studio, android-intent

I am programming a quiz-app where the player should have the possibility to sent his own questions to a customer feedback email address with his own question suggestions. The question I have now, is it possible to sent the data that the user types in the EditText fields to an E-mail address without using the address of the player?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you will have a server and REST API for authentication, serve quiz questions, verify answer etc.

Add one more REST API to above list to accept feedback. Your Android App should capture data from text field, and call REST API just like it would have called any other API. REST API can derive user information from an auth token. REST API on server can use third party email service eg. Sendgrid or AWS SES to eventually send an email to target email address.

If you are not performing user authentication, Android application can optionally send some additional information about user to the REST API.

If you are not using server itself, then you will have to consider using a server and maintain your own REST API, or opt for server-less architecture e.g. AWS Lambda.

In any case, you shall consider using one of the third party email service rather than setting your own email setup.